# c# query is not returning anything

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-2008, select

here is my query:

```
select reporttime, datapath, finalconc, instrument from batchinfo 
    join qvalues on batchinfo.rowid=qvalues.rowid where qvalues.rowid 
    in (select rowid from batchinfo where instrument LIKE '%TF1%' and reporttime
    like '10/%/2010%') and compound='ETG' and  name='QC1'
```

i am running it like this:

```
    // Create a database connection object using the connection string    
    OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString);

    // Create a database command on the connection using query    
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);
```

it does not return any results.

when i try this same query in sql server GUI it returns lots of rows

is there a problem specifically with the syntax of the query for c#?

please note that if i simplify the query like `select * from table`, there is no issue

Comment: Can you provide the code where you actually assign the value to `mySelectQuery`?

Comment: Run a query profiler to see the actual query (if any) being executed

Comment: What data type is your `reporttime` column? The name suggests it is temporal (`DATE`, `DATETIME`, etc) but the use of wildcards suggests it is text (`VARCHAR` etc).

Comment: @oneday its a varchar my frend

Comment: @postman make taht into an answer you were definitely right

Comment: Are any of the query criteria variable values in the code? Can you verify the exact query being run against the sql server? (a second for firing up sql profiler) Perhaps one of the criteria values isn't what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are connecting to the same database in your code?

On a side note do you need the inner select? Couldn't you write this query as follows.

```
  select reporttime,
         datapath,
         finalconc, 
         instrument 
    from batchinfo  
           join qvalues on batchinfo.rowid = qvalues.rowid
   where compound = 'ETG' 
     and name = 'QC1'
     and batchinfo.instrument like '%TF1%'
     and batchinfo.reporttime like '10/%/2010%'
```

Comment: wow this doesnt solve the problem but definitely gives me good insight into how to fix the sql

Comment: Thanks for that, I think, but I have seen a problem like this be as simple as connecting to test instead of dev

Answer (score 4):

Can you try using [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) instead of [OleDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand%28VS.71%29.aspx)?

According to MSDN it: `Represents a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure to execute against a SQL Server database.`

So if you really are using SQL Server 2008 you should probably use this.  Any reason you are not?

Comment: Ummmm i think in your situation it's as simple as replacing all occurrences of `OleDbCommand` and `OleDbConnenction` with `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection`.  They are very similar classes, they just serve different purposes.

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using to assign your SQL to `mySelectQuery` in your original post then?

Answer (score 2):

How are you setting up the mySelectQuery string? 
Could this be a problem with an escape character?

If you're not doing it already,

```
string mySelectQuery = @"query text here";
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would run query profiler to see what query (if any) is being run, and then go from there.

Comment: im running the profiler and it looks like it is fine. when running frmo the sql GUI its fine, however when i try to do from c# it doesnt return anything

Answer (score 1):

*Edit - Never mind, just read the comment that your date is in a varchar field.  Will leave this here since it may still be useful information.*

Try this:

```
reporttime like 'Oct%2010%'
```

I have a test table here and when I query it using

```
where LastModified like '11/%/2010%'
```

no rows are returned, although all of the rows in the table have dates in November 2010.  When I run the same query using `like 'Nov%2010%'`, it returns all rows.

Details can be found [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_2209321_2/Working-with-SQL-Server-DateTime-Variables-Part-Three---Searching-for-Particular-Date-Values-and-Ranges.htm):

> The LIKE clause can also be used to search for particular dates, as well. You need to remember that the LIKE clause is used to search character strings. Because of this the value which you are searching for will need to be represented in the format of an alphabetic date. The correct format to use is: MON DD YYYY HH:MM:SS.MMMAM, where MON is the month abbreviation, DD is the day, YYYY is the year, HH is hours, MM is minutes, SS is seconds, and MMM is milliseconds, and AM designates either AM or PM.

Comment: i appreciate your response, but like i said i tried the query and it was fine using the sql server gui